# I locked the quote in apex, but I can still do an update on it

Tags: apex

The update here completes without issue. That's not what I was expecting after locking the record. Please advise.

```
 public static Map<String, String> undoNotAwarded(String[] quoteIdsArray){
    Map<String, String> toastVariantToMessage = new Map<String, String>();
    String vendorList = '';

    List<Custom_Quote__c> quotes = [SELECT Id, Vendor_Name__r.Name, Status__c
                                          FROM Custom_Quote__c
                                          WHERE Id IN :quoteIdsArray];
    lockQuotes(quotes);

    for(Custom_Quote__c quote : quotes) {
        quote.Status__c = 'Ready for Review';
        vendorList += quote.Vendor_Name__r.Name + ', ';
    }

    try {
        update quotes;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
        String message = 'An error occurred. Emails were not sent to: ' + vendorList;
        toastVariantToMessage.put('error',message);
        return toastVariantToMessage;
    }
    
    String toastMessage = 'Status set to \'Ready for Review\' on these quotes: ' + vendorList;
    toastVariantToMessage.put('success',toastMessage);
    return toastVariantToMessage;
}
```

LockQuotes Private Method

```
    private static void lockQuotes(List<Custom_Quote__c> quotes){

    Approval.LockResult[] approvalLock = Approval.Lock(quotes, false);

    for(Approval.LockResult al : approvalLock) {
        if (al.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Successfully Locked Quote with ID: ' + al.getId());
        }
        else {
            // Operation failed, so get all errors                
            for(Database.Error err : al.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('Quote fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the record was locked? Here, `Approval.lock(quotes, false)` will keep going even if there were errors. Make sure you check your logs.

Comment: Does it matter if the Approval Process is inactive? @sfdcfox

Comment: Also, got success in the logs: 23:12:30:038 USER_DEBUG [222]|DEBUG|Successfully Locked Quote with ID: a4cDL000000hdds @sfdcfox

Comment: According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_approval.htm "Salesforce admins can edit locked records". Apex classes are executed with admin-like permissions, so that may explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Sander de Jong was correct in his comment: According to developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/… "Salesforce admins can edit locked records". Apex classes are executed with admin-like permissions, so that may explain it.

In my apex, it was locking from the beginning. The problem was that I was testing with my Sys Admin User. I created a different user with Profile that had Edit permission on Quote object. When that user updates the record, lock worked.